# Iterate through three lists multiple times sequentially picking one element from a list in each iteration

Tags: python, for-loop, iterator, nested-loops, string-interning

I want to iterate through each of the three lists sequentially picking one element from each list in every iteration.

```
subjects=["Americans","Indians"]
verbs=["plays","watch"]
objects=["Baseball","cricket"]
for i,j,k in zip(subjects,verbs,objects):
    print(i,j,k)
```

**The above code gives the output as follows:**

```
Americans plays Baseball

Indians watch cricket
```

**But the intended output is:**

```
Americans play Baseball.

Americans play Cricket.

Americans watch Baseball.

Americans watch Cricket.

Indians play Baseball.

Indians play Cricket.

Indians watch Baseball.

Indians watch Cricket.
```

Comment: use `itertools.product`: `for i,j,k in itertools.product(subjects,verbs,objects): print(i,j,k)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate as such for the solution:

```
subjects=["Americans","Indians"] 
verbs=["plays","watch"] 
objects=["Baseball","cricket"]


for s in subjects:
    for v in verbs:
        for o in objects:
            print(s,v,o+".")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `itertools.product` to get all the possible combinations and then print them

```
>>> subjects=["Americans","Indians"]
>>> verbs=["plays","watch"]
>>> objects=["Baseball","cricket"]
>>> 
>>> from itertools import product
>>> for x in product(subjects,verbs,objects):
...     print('{} {} {}'.format(*x))
... 
Americans plays Baseball
Americans plays cricket
Americans watch Baseball
Americans watch cricket
Indians plays Baseball
Indians plays cricket
Indians watch Baseball
Indians watch cricket
```

Answer (score 0):

`itertools.product` is the best solution for this, but if you don't want to import a module, the next most efficient solution would be a generator expression.

```py
subjects = ["Americans", "Indians"]
verbs = ["play", "watch"]
objects = ["Baseball", "Cricket"]

# paragraph = "\n".join(f"{s} {v} {o}." for s in subjects for v in verbs for o in objects)  # Alternative single-liner
for sentence in (f"{s} {v} {o}." for s in subjects for v in verbs for o in objects):
    print(sentence)
```

Output

```
Americans play Baseball.
Americans play Cricket.
Americans watch Baseball.
Americans watch Cricket.
Indians play Baseball.
Indians play Cricket.
Indians watch Baseball.
Indians watch Cricket.
```